# Find DATE patten

Tags: unix

I want to seach for Date pattern in my file and when found I have to insert "T" after the Date pattern.
Eg: My file contains: 2013-11-26 17:10:06

I have to find all the pattern 2013-11-26 and insert "T".

My output should be : 2013-11-26T17:10:06 .

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "2013-11-26 17:10:06"|sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/&T/g'

sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/&T/g' filename
```